# Download file using Download Manager from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app that allows users to select a file from a list view and download it. I have an `AsyncTask` that fetches the files and for each file sets an `onClickListener` which allows to download that file when the users clicks it. I have all over the internet but I can't get a download manager to work from an `AsynTask`. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What aspect of the solution does not work?  Is the HTTP connection failing?  Are you not getting a result to publish on the UI thread?  Some more information would be needed to provide a useful answer.

Comment: After I click on the file I get a notification that the file is downloading but it doesn't appear on the notification tray

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple example:

```
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            String dir = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC;
            dir += "/klp";
            File fileDir = new File(dir);
            if (!fileDir.isDirectory()) {
                fileDir.mkdir();
            }


            Toast.makeText(Detail.this, "Download song " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Download File
            DownloadManager.Request request = 
                    new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription(nameFile);
            request.setTitle(name);
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir, nameFile);


            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);   


        }
    });
```